# HP DL160 G6 firmware iso

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, firmware

I have an issue updating HP Proliant DL160 G6. I downloaded some firmware on the internet but its not working. I haven't had luck googling on the internet for a reliable firmware ISO to use. 
The server is installed with the latest Linux Debian 8.
Is there any recommended link , one can suggest that i can download from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to download bootable ISO image of [Service Pack for ProLiant (SPP)](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/) disk. If you haven't dvd drive you can write this iso image to USB stick by [HP USB Key Utility](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_2aa85604194243afbdb1c29a34), but it works only under Windows OS.

Comment: Thank you , i have tried to download the ISO from the above link, it seems its only possible if one has warranty or active support on the product of which i don't have any.

Comment: I downloaded it 2 years ago without any active​ support. Maybe you need to pass registration form.

Comment: Ok thanks, i have tried after registration but no success. Let me try to look on the internet if there are any other options.

Comment: You can find it via torrent. And check md5sum on HP site.

Comment: Thank you, i got it(201604....). but when running the firmware it hangs after selecting either interactive or automatic installation and gets stuck .